Not possible to connect to redis server
I am running a .NET application inside a Docker container and trying to connect it to an Azure Redis Cache instance. While I can successfully connect to the Redis instance using redis-cli from within the Docker container, the .NET application fails to connect and gives the following error:
"StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code.\n   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log, Nullable`1 serverType, EndPointCollection endpoints) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 708\n   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 673\n   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 651\n   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)

I have correctly configured appsettings.json and added it to my program.cs
Verified the connection to Azure Redis Cache using redis-cli from within the Docker container:

redis-cli -h ghsdata.redis.cache.windows.net -p 6380 --tls

This works and I can run commands like PING and SET.
Configured appsettings.json with the correct connection string, including the hostname, password, and SSL settings.
Verified Docker Compose setup to ensure the appsettings.json is correctly mounted and environment variables are passed.
What shall I do to resolve this error?
Configured appsettings.json with the correct connection string, including the hostname, password, and SSL settings.

I created a simple ASP .Net application and successfully connected it to Azure Redis Cache instance.

Make sure your Redis connection is correctly formatted in appsettings.json
Install the package StackExchange.Redis in your application.

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Redis": {
    "ConnectionString": "nuxtredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=<your-password>,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"
  }
}

program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using StackExchange.Redis;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(sp =>
{
    var configuration = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(builder.Configuration["Redis:ConnectionString"]);
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
});
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapGet("/redis-test", async context =>
{
    var connectionMultiplexer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>();
    var db = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();   
    await db.StringSetAsync("test_key", "test_value");   
    var value = await db.StringGetAsync("test_key");
    if (value.IsNullOrEmpty)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Value not found in Redis.");
    }
    else
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Value from Redis: {value}");
    }
});
app.MapGet("/set-redis-value", async context =>
{
    var connectionMultiplexer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>();
    var db = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

    var key = context.Request.Query["key"].ToString();
    var value = context.Request.Query["value"].ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
       
        await db.StringSetAsync(key, value);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Successfully set key '{key}' with value '{value}' in Redis.");
    }
    else
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Key or value cannot be empty.");
    }
});
app.Run();

Index.cshtml:
@page
@model dynamic
<h2>ASP.NET Core Redis Connection Test</h2>
<p>
    <label for="keyInput">Key:</label>
    <input type="text" id="keyInput" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="valueInput">Value:</label>
    <input type="text" id="valueInput" />
</p>
<button id="setRedisValueButton">Set Redis Value</button>
<button id="testRedisButton">Test Redis Connection</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>   document.getElementById("setRedisValueButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
        const key = document.getElementById("keyInput").value;
        const value = document.getElementById("valueInput").value;

        const response = await fetch(`/set-redis-value?key=${key}&value=${value}`);
        const result = await response.text();
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
    });   document.getElementById("testRedisButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/redis-test');
        const result = await response.text();
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
    });
</script>

Local output:

I've successfully deployed the app to azure app service via Azure container registry.
Output after deployment:

I've tested whether the Redis is connected successfully or not by using the Redis-cli.
Run the below command
redis-cli -h <REDIS-HOST> -p <REDIS-PORT> -a <REDIS-PASSWORD> --tls

I was successfully able to store and retrieve keys and values in Redis.

